# What makes signed integers behave differently?

Tags: assembly

In this example of x86_64 hex/disassembled code I see:

```
48B80000000000000000 mov rax, 0x0

    Signed Byte 52
    Unsigned Byte   52
    Signed Short    14388
    Unsigned Short  14388
    Signed Int  943863860
    Unsigned Int    943863860
    Signed Int64    3472328296363079732
    Unsigned Int64  3472328296363079732
    Float   4.630555e-05
    Double  1.39804332763832e-76
    String  48B80000000000000000
```

which to me appears to have the same functionality as:

```
48C7C000000000 mov rax, 0x0

    48C7C000000000

    Signed Byte 52
    Unsigned Byte   52
    Signed Short    14388
    Unsigned Short  14388
    Signed Int  927152180
    Unsigned Int    927152180
    Signed Int64    3472328377950746676
    Unsigned Int64  3472328377950746676
    Float   1.163599e-05
    Double  1.39806836023098e-76
    String  48C7C000000000
```

How is the first example treated differently from the second example?

Comment: This question would probably be better off at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C7 opcode moves a signed 32 bit number into a 64 bit register. It will sign-extend it, which means it will fill the high bits with whatever the sign bit of the source is, so that it will have the same value when interpreted as a signed number.

Since it's an immediate value, the only difference that you'll see is that the top one will support an immediate value of up to 64 bits long, but the bottom one will only support up to 32 bits.

Here are the relevant lines from Intel's reference manual.

```
REX.W + B8+ rd    MOV r64, imm64     OI     Valid     N.E.     Move imm64 to r64.
REX.W + C7 /0     MOV r/m64, imm32   MI     Valid     N.E.     Move imm32 sign extended to 64-bits to r/m64.
```

Comment: @dirk-holsoppie — Thank you very much. Your explanation confirms what I was thinking; the first example is targeted at 64-bit exclusively, which makes perfect sense given the first example opcode is located within a 64-bit binary.

Comment: The second one is a 64-bit instruction too, since it uses a 64-bit register but the immediate value that it takes is a signed 32-bit number.

Comment: I see. I'm still a bit (no pun intended) unclear as to when it's best use one over the other, but your answer definitely explains the differences very well. Without knowing what the source is which one would you use typically?

Comment: The advantages the second one has is that it's shorter (it takes up 7 bytes instead of 10) and it can move into a memory location as well as a register. The second can only move into a register but it lets you move a 64-bit value instead of just a 32-bit one.

Comment: If you tried to put a 64-bit value into the 32-bit one what might happen?

Comment: You can't. There's only 32-bits in the instruction to encode the value. If you were doing in assembly language, the assembler would use the B8 opcode if you were using a register; if you were trying to move a 64-bit directly into memory it should complain that the operands are incorrect, like it would if you tried `mov rax, ebx` or anything else that doesn't have an opcode that supports it.

Comment: GNU as would just take the lower 32 bits and issue a warning on that like this, which I just encountered an hour or so ago: `Warning: 68719476736 shortened to 0`